# Hashmap entries are replacing when adding new key value pair

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have to add some list data to hashmap using loop.When i add the second list to the hashmap with a different key the first list in the hashmap is replaced with the second list also.Why this happens?Please help me to solve this. Below is my code

```
private List<COAAccount> dataCoa=new ArrayList<COAAccount>();
private List<COAAccount> finalList=new ArrayList<COAAccount>();
private Map<Integer,List<COAAccount>> brkDBMap;
private Map<Integer,List<COAAccount>> brkVwMap=new HashMap<Integer, List<COAAccount>>();
```

I have loaded some values to brkDBMap.Then,

```
Iterator itDB = brkDBMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (itDB.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)itDB.next();
                int key=(int) pairs.getKey();
                List<COAAccount> valueList=(List<COAAccount>) pairs.getValue();
                if(brkVwMap.containsKey(key)) {
                    System.out.println("****EXIST******");
                }else{
                    //finalList=new ArrayList<COAAccount>();
                    finalList = new ArrayList<COAAccount>(dataCoa);

                    Iterator<COAAccount> itertrMap=valueList.iterator();
                    while(itertrMap.hasNext()){
                        int s=-1;
                        COAAccount importCoa=new COAAccount();
                        importCoa=restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/SaveIt/stock/getCopyBudget", itertrMap.next(),COAAccount.class);

                        switch (importCoa.getAccPerId()) {
                            case 0: s =9;
                                    break;
                            case 1: s=10;
                                    break;
                            case 2: s=11;
                                    break;
                            case 3: s=0;
                                    break;
                            case 4: s=1;
                                    break;
                            case 5: s=2;
                                    break;
                            case 6: s=3;
                                    break;
                            case 7: s=4;
                                    break;
                            case 8: s=5;
                                    break;
                            case 9: s=6;
                                    break;
                            case 10:s=7;
                                    break;
                            case 11:s=8;
                                    break;
                            default:
                                    break;
                        }
                        COAAccount impCAcct=new COAAccount();
                        impCAcct=finalList.get(s);
                        impCAcct.setBudBrk(importCoa.getiD(), importCoa.getBudID(), importCoa.getAccPerId(), importCoa.getBudgetAmount(), importCoa.getDescAdd());

                        finalList.set(s, impCAcct);
                    }
                    brkVwMap.put(key,finalList);

                }


            }
```

Here brkDBMap and brkVwMap are hashmap.I need to add list to brkVwMap.If i want to insert values "Account1" and "Account2" for keys 1 and 2 respectively to the brkVwMap,then after adding "Account2" the map become {1=[Account2], 2=[Account2]} instead of {1=[Account1], 2=[Account2]}

Comment: Are the keys the same, or different?

Comment: keys are different.Firstly i am adding value with key 1.then i am adding value with key 2, but it cause to change the value field of 1 also

Comment: For starters, use generics and format your code.

Comment: @KJEjava48 What is the content in itDB  ?

Comment: How about `map.computeIfAbsent(key, k-> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);`?

Comment: @KJEjava48 What do you know about objects and references?

Comment: P.S. Don't use raw types! `Iterator` is generic! `Map.Entry` is generic! All of your redundant and horribly unsafe casting scares me...

Comment: Then how should i do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
brkVwMap.put(key,finalList);
```

The value you add to your map is `finalList`, which is initialized by :

```
//finalList=new ArrayList<COAAccount>();
finalList=dataCoa;
```

You didn't show where `dataCoa` is initialized, but I suspect that it's initialized once, so all the values in your map would be identical.

The line you commented out makes more sense.
If you want to initialize `finalList` with the content of `dataCoa`, but still have different values for different keys of the map, you should write :

```
finalList = new ArrayList<COAAccount>(dataCoa);
```

Comment: I have initialise dataCoa and it contains some value also.I didn't show it in this code

Comment: @KJEjava48 I'm sure you initialized it, but since you are using the same object as the value in your map for multiple keys, changing the value of one key changes the value for all the other keys.

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: I think after this step the replacement takes place impCAcct.setBudBrk(importCoa.getiD(), importCoa.getBudID(), importCoa.getAccPerId(), importCoa.getBudgetAmount(), importCoa.getDescAdd());

Answer (score 0):

With `finalList=dataCoa;` you create a shallow copy, so every reference you have using finalList (i.e. each value in your HashMap) points to the same List *dataCoa* and you change dataCoa whenever changing a value in finalList.

As an example you could use something like this:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("a");

List<String> b = a;
b.add("b");

List<String> c = new ArrayList<String>(a);
c.add("c");

System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(c);
```

This way, b is the same list as a, while c is a deep copy, where all elements are copied into a new list and changes don't reflect on a and b.
The resulting output is:

```
[a, b]
[a, b]
[a, b, c]
```

So Eran is right in saying your code

```
//finalList=new ArrayList<COAAccount>();
finalList=dataCoa;
```

should be:

```
finalList=new ArrayList<COAAccount>(dataCoa);
//finalList=dataCoa;
```

The second line of course has to be commented/deleted, otherwise you overwrite the new List with the same reference that made problems earlier ;)